# cmd.exe bleeding through when run as scheduled task as SYSTEM

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

We are running a batch file as a scheduled task on Windows XP as the SYSTEM user.
99% of the time our users don't even know this is running, because the command window doesn't show up on the screen because it's being run as the SYSTEM user.

The other 1% of the time the batch file "bleeds through" the screen and looks like the below image (edited for privacy).

Anyone ever seen this?  Or have a solution??

[image: Bleed-through]

Comment: Could be a display driver issue.  Check that the drivers are up to date.  You might be better off asking on Super User, since the problem isn't really directly related to programming.  PS - upgrading to a supported OS would almost certainly fix this, because the task would be run in a non-interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help :-

Try this

cmd /c "c:\full\path\to\your\batchfile.bat"

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.  I know it's to close the windows after execution, but it does go away after execution.  

The problem is that this shows during execution when it shouldn't produce a window at all (when run under the SYSTEM account).